# How to send mail using cake php and where to start?

Tags: php, cakephp, xampp

I wanna try to send mail using cake php. I have no experience of sending mail. So, I don't know where to start. Is it need to make mail server? If need, how to make mail server and how to send mail? Please explain step by step. I really don't know where to start.

**I'm using xampp and now I test my site at localhost.**

I tested following link:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1286/Sending-a-basic-message

but error occurred **cannot be accessed directly.**

and then I add code from the following link:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1290/Sending-A-Message-Using-SMTP

So, my code is following:

```
    function _sendMail(){
    $this->Email->to = 'user@gmail.com';
    $this->Email->bcc = array('secret@example.coom');
    $this->Email->subject = 'Welcome to our really cool things';
    $this->Email->replyTo = 'support@example.com';
    $this->Email->from = 'Online Application <app@example.coom>';
    $this->Email->template = 'simple_message';
    $this->Email->sendAs = 'both';

    $this->Email->smtpOptions = array(
            'port' =>'25',
        'timeout' => '30',
        'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
        'username' => 'my_mail@gmail.com',
        'password' =>'aaa',
    );
    $this->Email->delivery = 'smtp';
    $this->Email->send();
   }
```

but error still occurred. But, I didn't make any mail server.Is that OK?

Comment: Show us the **controller method** that this code is in and how you try to call it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling this is to do with your XAMPP configuration:

Try opening "php.ini", it should be somewhere in your server files.

Search for the attribute called “SMTP” in the php.ini file.Generally you can find the line “SMTP=localhost“. change the localhost to the smtp server name of your ISP. And, there is another attribute called “smtp_port” which should be set to 25.I’ve set the following values in my php.ini file.

```
SMTP = smtp.wlink.com.np
smtp_port = 25
```

Restart the apache server so that PHP modules and attributes will be reloaded.

ow try to send the mail using the mail() function:

```
mail(“you@yourdomain.com”,”test subject”,”test body”);
```

If you get the following warning:

```
Warning: mail() [function.mail]: “sendmail_from” not set in php.ini or custom “From:” header missing in C:\Program Files\xampp\htdocs\testmail.php on line 1
```

Specify the following headers and try to send the mail again:

```
$headers = ‘MIME-Version: 1.0′ . “\r\n”;
$headers .= ‘Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1′ . “\r\n”;
$headers .= ‘From: sender@sender.com’ . “\r\n”;
mail(“you@yourdomain.com”,”test subject”,”test body”,$headers);
```

source: http://roshanbh.com.np/2007/12/sending-e-mail-from-localhost-in-php-in-windows-environment.html

Answer (score 1):

Naming the controller function with a leading underscore is Cake's backwards compatible way of designating that the function should be *protected*, i.e. that the function should not be accessible as a normal controller action. That means you can't access `FooController::_sendMail()` using the URL `/foo/_sendMail`, or any other URL for that matter. You should be seeing this, which IMO is a pretty good error message:

> **Private Method in UsersController**
>
> Error: `FooController::_sendMail()` cannot be accessed directly.

Remove the leading underscore, that's all. This problem has nothing to do with sending email.

Comment: Thanks. I get it. Is the message really arrived? I try to send above function but the message is not arrived at my gmail.why?

Comment: That's a different topic I don't know. Did `Email->send()` actually return `true`?

Comment: Please check out my answer below, it may help you. XAMPP is often not configured to send email.

Comment: I wanna know about $this->Email->smtpOptions, and I don't understand where to supply username and password. Sometimes username and password are filled in by gmail but sometimes they are not. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
//load mail component in controller
var $components = array('Mail');

//then do

$this->Email->sendAs="html";
$this->Email->from="some@domain.com";
$this->Email->to="someone@domain.com";       
$this->Email->subject="Your subject;
$this->Email->send("Your message);
```

//Check cakephp manual for more reference: http://book.cakephp.org/

Comment: I already tried just like this but not OK and error occurred  **cannot be accessed directly**

Comment: @shariphwar You are [still](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8396806/how-to-send-mail-by-cake-php) mixing up issues! To me it seems you're just putting that email code in a controller action that is protected and cannot be accessed. Your email code is fine! Give us more information about the surround real issue!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example code for sending an HTML email with CakePHP's Email component

---

Ex controller : EmailController.php

```
<?php
class EmailController extends AppController{

public $components=array('Email');

function send(){

//create an array of values to be replaced in email html template//
$emailValues=array('name'=>'MyName','phone'=>'MyPhone');
$this->set('emailValues',$emailValues);//pass to template //
$this->Email->to = 'to@address.com'; //receiver email id
$this->Email->subject = 'Subject Line';
$this->Email->replyTo = 'reply@address.com'; //reply to email//
$this->Email->from = 'SenderName<sender@address.com>'; //sender
$this->Email->template = 'sample';//email template //
$this->Email->sendAs = 'html';
if($this->Email->send()){
//mail send //
}

}

?>
```

---

Now create the email template in folder /Views/Email/html/
ie the template path should be
/Views/Email/html/sample.ctp

sample.ctp

```
<?php

Hi <?php echo $emailValues['name'];?> <br>
Thanks for sharing your phone number '<?php echo $emailValues['phone'];?>' .
<br>


?>
```